Inconsistent behaviour is resending data messages using FCM in terminated state
I want to send multiple notifications to my app. The user can be offline so Firebase will collapse all the notifications. I searched and found that data messages are not collapsible. I switched to use data messages and it worked fine in debug, profile, and release in all states (foreground, background and terminated) except for terminated. After reconnecting and the app is terminated, some data messages are received and some are not.
public function sendDataMessage($deviceTokens, $data = [], $priority = "high")
{
    $messaging = app('firebase.messaging');
    $clean_data = $data;
    if (isset($data["type"]) && $data["type"] == "chat" && $data["action"] == "receiveMessage") {
        unset($clean_data["fcm_message"]);
    }
    $messages = [];
    foreach ($deviceTokens as $token) {
        try {
            if (isset($data["type"]) && $data["type"] == "chat" && $data["action"] == "receiveMessage") {
                $chat_message = $data["fcm_message"];
                $clean_data["title"] = Chats::select("name")->find($data["chat_id"])->name;
                $clean_data["body"] = $chat_message["sender"]["name"] . ": " . ($chat_message["content"]["type"] == "Text" ? $chat_message["content"]["body"] : $chat_message["content"]["type"]);
            }
            $messages[] = CloudMessage::withTarget('token', $token)
                ->withData($clean_data)
                ->withAndroidConfig(AndroidConfig::fromArray([
                    'priority' => 'high',  // Use high priority
                    'ttl' => 86400 * 28, // 4 weeks in seconds
                ]))
                ->withApnsConfig(ApnsConfig::fromArray([
                    'headers' => [
                        'apns-expiration' => strval(time() + 86400 * 28), // Expiry timestamp
                        'apns-priority' => '10',
                    ],
                    'payload' => [
                        'aps' => [
                            // 'sound' => 'default',
                            "content-available" => 1,
                            "mutable-content" => 1
                        ],
                    ],
                ]));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $e;
        }
    }
    try {
        $report = $messaging->sendAll($messages);
    } catch (NotFound $e) {
        return $e;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return $e;
    }

    return $report->successes()->count();
}

This is the code for sending data message from the server. Each received data message will cause a local notification to pop up. Can someone explain why if the app is terminated and offline, multiple messages are sent, and then reconnect, sometimes it works and sometimes some earlier messages are not received.
EDIT
I tested it with app terminated but still have connection, it works but sometimes it still drops some messages.
I am starting to believe that it is because of how fast these messages are sent, firebase may skip a few but still why in terminated state, it works flawlessly in foreground and background.
